# Change status of two records with one button click with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have upload form from which Admin can upload different documents. The goal is to have only one active document at the time in the table.

So, admin upload new document which then marks as a Active. After a few days he can upload another one which by default is Inactive. If the admin make the second document to be Active, then the first one should become Inactive.

This is what I have so far.

The route for update

```
Route::post('/admin/media/{media}', 'Admin\MediaController@completedUpdate')->name('completedUpdate');
```

The view with the buttons

```
<td>@if($value->status == 1) 
        <form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $value->id) }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}                          
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="changeStatus" value="0">Active</button>
        </form>                    
    @else
        <form action="{{ route('completedUpdate', $value->id) }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}                              
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="changeStatus" value="1">Inactive</button>
        </form>                                                 
    @endif
</td>
```

And the function in the controller

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, Mediakit $media)
{
    $data = DB::table('media')->get();
    foreach($data as $media) {
        if ( $media->status == 1 ) {
            DB::table('media')->update(['status', 0]);
        }
    }
    $media->status = $request->changeStatus;
    $media->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Status changed!');
}
```

Current error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `media` set `0` = status, `1` = 0)

I'm not even sure that the function should be like this. What I've tough to do is on button click to select all records, loop them and update all to `0 (inactive)` then change only the clicked one to `1(active)`.

Comment: `DB::table('media')->update(['status' => 0]);`

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for the help! Is this solution good from performance or logical view? I mean what if someday there are 10,000 or 100,000 records I guess will be a bit slow while update each row..

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong I think. This query updates the status for all the records in the table, because you do not have any where clauses, but yet you loop each record and compare its status.

Comment: DB::table('media')->update(['status' => 0])->where('status','1'); This will change only those that are currently a status of 1.

Comment: @Petay87 I've got `"Call to a member function where() on integer"`. I've switched `where` and `update` and it's fixed.

Comment: Sorry, the update should be at the end. SO DB::table('media')->where('status',1)->update(['status' => 0]);

Comment: Yes, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
DB::table('media')->update(['status', 0]);
```

To

```
DB::table('media')->where('status',1)->update(['status' => 0]);
```

This will update All entries in the media table to have a status of 0 where the status is currently 1.

You full function will look closer to this:

```
public function completedUpdate(Request $request, Mediakit $media)
{
    // Set ALL records to a status of 0
    DB::table('media')->where('status',1)->update(['status' => 0]);

    // Set the passed record to a status of what ever is passed in the Request
    $media->status = $request->changeStatus;
    $media->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Status changed!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is it better to use `while/do` instead of `if` in this case? Since I always will have only one active status at the time..

Comment: You don't actually need the if or foreach loop. That query I gave you will update ALL entries where the status is 1. So looping through each record is not required. Just update all records to be a status of 0 and THEN insert your new one with a status of 1. This will leave you with only the single record with a status of 1.

Comment: I tough that I need actual loop trough the records in order to find out which one is current active. This way is working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: You could have done it the way you wanted but the code for the update would have been a little different and it would have taken a lot longer as your database grew in size. This answer should keep things nice and fast.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again for the help!